# How to copy a given file from a pre-determined directory (by filename)

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration here.

I have a directory where files are being copied to by another service activator.

The files need to stay there until their status on the DB is `processed` - then I need to move the files to the next directory where they will be sent (via SFTP) to their final destination.

I have a polling channel that fetches a list of files in the `processed` status (from DB). Then I split the incoming list (each `Message` now contains the name of the file I need to move to the next directory in its `payload`.)

How do I tell the `inbound-channel-adapter` to read only the given file (I have the full path to the file) from the defined directory and copy/move it to the next directory?

This is my config so far:

```
<!-- File Adapters: Inbound -->
<file:inbound-channel-adapter 
          id="filesInChannelAdapter"
          filename-regex="/^#jsonPath(payload,'$.filename')$/"   <<< this does not work     
          directory="${inbound.dir}" />

<!-- Service Activators -->
<int:service-activator input-channel="filesInChannelAdapter"
                       output-channel="filesOutChannelAdapter"
                       id="fileCopyActivator"
                       method="handleFile"
                       ref="fileCopyHandler"/>

 <!-- File Adapters: Outbound -->
 <file:outbound-channel-adapter 
        id="filesOutChannelAdapter"
        preserve-timestamp="true"
        delete-source-files="true"
        directory="${outbound.dir}"/>
```

Is there a way to read a file in without having to poll a directory?

How else could I copy the file from directory A to B after querying its status from the DB? (via a REST endpoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileWritingMessageHandler` (`<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>`) can do that for you. So, you REST endpoint brings a file name, you check it state in DB, e.g. via `<filter>` and then go to the `<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>` with the `File` payload and `Files.move()` will be performed for you.

Comment: Thanks Artem! I'll give it a try and report back

Comment: I suppose the right question at this point is: what is the correct way to load the file (from its filename) into the payload for sending it to the `outbound-channel-adapter` - is doing a `new File("path/to/file/filename")` the way to go?

Comment: Yes, that's true. To perform a `Files.move()` you really have to provide `File` payload. Since you have already its path, that should be easy `transformer` for you. Note: when you create `File` object, you don't load its content to the memory. That's why we use `move` - OS-specific utility without impacting Java memory.

Comment: Yes, you do! How about just to try it and come back if that doesn't work? ;)

Comment: Great! created a `transformer` that did it